# When referring to a culture, should that culture's name be capitalised?

Tags: capitalization

For instance, which of these is correct?

> Gather and analyse Maori learner achievement data...

or

> Gather and analyse maori learner achievement data...

Answer (score 2):

Proper nouns need to be capitalized. The name of a specific culture is a proper noun and as such should be capitalized.

I don't know what the authoratitive references are for grammar rules, but here is a reference to the rules of capitalization at [grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp)

Answer (score 1):

According to a style guide provided by [Towson University](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/capitalization_rules.htm), we could apply either rule number 8 or 10:

> 8:  countries, nationalities, and specific languages
>
> 10:  names of national, political, racial, social, civic, and athletic groups

All of which indicate that, yes, Maori should be capitalized in your example.